# How to reindex an array in php without copying it

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$x = [1 => "uno", 2 => "dos", 5 => "tres", 6 => "cuatro"];
```

And I need:

```
$x = [1 => "uno", 2 => "dos", 3 => "tres", 4 => "cuatro"];
```

I tried using array_values($x) but it starts counting from zero index. How could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I tried using array_values($x) but it starts counting from zero index.

Use it together with `array_combine`, and provide an array of values 1, 2, ... created via `range` to supply the desired keys:

```
$result = array_combine(range(1, count($x)), $x);
```

Comment: I haven't tested to be sure, but I think you can do without the array_values call, because array_combine will iterate over the original array regardless of its keys.

Comment: @IMSoP yeah you're right, the keys of the input data to array_combine don't really matter.